# Convert alternate char to uppercase

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to java programming. I want to print a string with alternate characters in UpperCase.

```
String x=jTextField1.getText();
x=x.toLowerCase();
int y=x.length();
for(int i=1;i<=y;i++)
{}
```

I don't know how to proceed further. I want to do this question with the help of looping and continue function.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, java indexes start at `0` (not `1`). I think you are asking for something as simple as alternating calls to [`Character.toLowerCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29) and [`Character.toUpperCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) on the result of [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (remainder of division) 2.

```
String x = jTextField1.getText();
for (int i = 0, len = x.length(); i < len; i++) {
    char ch = x.charAt(i);
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
    } else {
        System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Why can't the condition for i<len be i<=len?

Comment: Because you'll get an Exception when you call charAt(Len); the first index is 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Test
public void alternateUppercase(){
    String testString = "This is a !!!!! test - of the emergency? broadcast System.";

    char[] arr = testString.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    boolean makeUppercase = true;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(makeUppercase && Character.isLetter(arr[i])) {
            arr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]);
            makeUppercase = false;
        } else if (!makeUppercase && Character.isLetter(arr[i])) {
            makeUppercase = true;
        }
    }
    String convertedString = String.valueOf(arr);
    System.out.println(convertedString);
}
```

Comment: None of these other answers account for symbols and spaces :P

Answer (score 1):

Strings start at index 0 and finish at index `x.length()-1`

To look up a String by index you can use `String.charAt(i)`

To convert a character to upper case you can do `Character.toUpperCase(ch)`;

I suggest you build a `StringBuilder` from these characters which you can `toString()` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Using as much of your code as I could, here's what I got. First I made a string called build that will help you build your resulting string. Also, I changed the index to go from [0,size-1] not [1,size]. Using modulo devision of 2 helps with the "every other" bit.

```
String build =""
String x=jTextField1.getText();
x=x.toLowerCase();
int y=x.length();
for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
{
     if(i%2==0){
        build+=Character.toUpperCase(x.charAt(i));
     else{
        build+=x.charAt(i);
     }
}
x=build; //not necessary, you could just use build.
```

Happy oding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it using the 65 distnace of lower case and upper case ABCabc from the unicode table like:

```
String str = "abbfFDdshFSDjdFDSsfsSdoi".toLowerCase();

char c;
boolean state = false; 
String newStr = "";
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
    c = str.charAt(o);

    if (state){
         newStr += c;
    }
    else {
         newStr += c + 65;
    }
    state = !state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a slicker way to do this, but this will work for a 2 minute-answer:

```
public String homeWork(){
        String x = "Hello World";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<=x.length();i++){
             char c = x.charAt(i);
             if(i%2==0){
                sb.append(String.valueOf(c).toUpperCase());
             } else {
                sb.append(String.valueOf(c).toLowerCase());
             }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

To explain i%2==0, if the remainder of i divided by 2 is equal to zero (even numbered) return true

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrintingStringInAlternativeCase {
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        String testString = "TESTSTRING";
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
                output += Character.toUpperCase(testString.toCharArray()[i]);
            }else
            {
                output += Character.toLowerCase(testString.toCharArray()[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Newly generated string is as follow: "+ output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Stirng");
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i)));
        }
    }

    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 Solution:

```
static String getMixedCase(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                    .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i % 2 == 1 ? chars[i] : Character.toUpperCase(chars[i])))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello";
        StringBuffer strNew = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                strNew.append(Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)));
            } else {
                strNew.append(Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i)));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(strNew);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the OP's problem, but an explanation will help everyone understand how/why.