# Change the case of every alternate char

Tags: java, string

I want to write a code in `Java` which does make changes to case of a alphabet character in an alternating fashion(either make it lowercase or uppercase)

For Example:

```java
changeCapitalization("hey 123 ABC idk");       // hEy 123 AbC iDk
changeCapitalization("abcdef ghijk 12 abc");   // aBcDeF gHiJk 1 AbC
```

Comment: I don't understand why the final word of the second example is `AbC`.  It seems it should be `aBc` to me.

Comment: why does this looks like an assignment?

Comment: Please show us some of your try and code. We can not present you a direct code as a service. Also you have not shown any logic to do this.

Comment: The most recent alphabetic character was lowercase, so the A needs to be capitalized. (Numbers don’t have case.) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert alternate char to uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051983/convert-alternate-char-to-uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder` to build new string and `boolean` marker to change between lower/upper letter case.

```
public static String changeCapitalization(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    boolean upperCase = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            buf.append(upperCase ? Character.toUpperCase(ch) : Character.toLowerCase(ch));
            upperCase = !upperCase;
        } else
            buf.append(ch);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str ="hello THERE";
String new_str="";
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    String c =Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
    if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))){
        c=c.toLowerCase();  
        new_str+=c; 
    }
    else if(Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))){
        c=c.toUpperCase();
        new_str+=c;
    }
    else if(c.equals(" ")){
        new_str+=" ";
    }
}
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(new_str);
```

}

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).